# codenameone and jformdesigner

Tags: java, user-interface, interface-builder, codenameone, jform-designer

Can a form designed in JFormdesigner be used in a codenameone application? If so, how? I know I can start the form from the main class with new LoginForm().show(); but not sure if the generated codes by JFormdesigner will work with codenaeone.

Thanks.

P.S. But if there is another form designer that would work e.g. the IntelliJ Idea GUI builder.

Comment: You are aware that cn1 does have its own deigner?

Answer (score 1):

No, jformdesigner creates swing gui and not a CN1 Form.